# Not setting iframe src after token expire

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, azure, iframe

I have a website that uses Azure AD to authenticate, within that site I have an iframe that also uses Azure AD to authenticate. The Problem I am facing is that the access token expires after 30-60 min and then arent authenticated till a page refresh. So I wrote the code to refresh the page and store the current url of the iframe in session storage and on reload put that url in the src of iframe. All this works untill the token expires then the page always goes to the original iframe source. This is the code:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
document.domain = 'company.com';
if (sessionStorage.getItem('url') == null) {
window.location;
 } else {
document.getElementById("MSOPageViewerWebPart_WebPartWPQ2").src = sessionStorage.getItem('url');
};
$(window).bind("load", function() {
sessionStorage.removeItem('url');
setTimeout(refresh, 30000);
});
function refresh () {
var myURL = document.getElementById("MSOPageViewerWebPart_WebPartWPQ2").contentDocument.location.href;
sessionStorage.setItem('url', myURL);
top.parent.location.href = top.parent.location.href;
 };

</script>
```

If anyone could till me how to modify this code so that no matter what the iframe goes to the url in session storage that would be great.

Comment: Are the two Web Apps in the same Azure AD application?

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT No they are in different Azure AD applications, and they are using the azure app proxy.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is that when it fire `refresh()`, it will at last refresh the top windows, so all the script and DOMs will refresh and initialize. So your iframe always goes to the original page.

Please consider the following code snippet:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
document.domain = 'company.com';
if (sessionStorage.getItem('url') == null) {
window.location;
 } else {
$("#MSOPageViewerWebPart_WebPartWPQ2").attr('src',sessionStorage.getItem('url'));
};
$(window).bind("load", function() {
sessionStorage.removeItem('url');
setTimeout(refresh, 30000);
});
function refresh () {
    console.log('refresh')
    var myURL = $("#MSOPageViewerWebPart_WebPartWPQ2").get(0).contentWindow.location;
    console.log(myURL);
    sessionStorage.setItem('url', myURL);
    console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('url'));
    // top.parent.location.href = top.parent.location.href;
 };
</script>
```